# Why conda doesn't find correct PYTHONPATHS of the local virtual enviroment?

Tags: python-2.7, conda

Edit: The aim of this work is to build a conda environment to replace bash exports. Therefore bash exports has been disabled.

I have created a local conda virtual environment named `my_env` using pre installed conda specification file called `my_env.txt` (same as `requirment.txt` )

```
conda create --prefix <path/to/my_env_directory> --file <path/to/my_env.txt>

i.e. conda create --prefix /hjs/jen/projects/my_env --file /hjs/jen/projects/project1/my_env.txt
```

And I have placed my `paths.pth` file in `/hjs/jen/projects/my_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paths.pth`

However, it doesn't find the correct local `PYTHONPATHS` as shown below.

When I run `python -c "import sys; print '\n'.join(sys.path)"` to check `PYTHONPATHS`, I get

```
/usr/lib/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/hjs/jen/project/my_env/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/net/home/j/jen/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0
```

So basically conda should not find any `PYTHONPATH` in `/net/home/j/jen/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` as it is NOT in local env but user specific (it's in `home` and `jen` is the user name) but it does!

To test this I've created a new `test_env.pth` file  at `hjs/jen/projects/my_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/test_env.pth` and sure enough it did not find this new `PYTHONPATH`

However, when I recreate the environment and delete both `*.pth` files and replace them in `/net/home/j/jen/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/test_paths.pth`, conda does find all the `PYTHONPATHS` as before as well as `/hjs/jen/test_test`

```
/usr/lib/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/hjs/jen/project/my_env/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/net/home/j/jen/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/net/home/j/jen/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/hjs/jen/test_test
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0
```

So basically I don't want conda to find any PYTHONPATH environment variables in `/net/home/j/jen/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`/ but ONLY in `hjs/jen/projects/my_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`. How do I achieve this?

Further info: `which python` shows only one installation of python inside the `env`

I am using `python 2.7`

Comment: Hi Jenny. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you please post the output of ```$ echo $PYTHONPATH``` from your command line.

Comment: Hi jwalton3141: Thanks a lot for the warm welcome. echo $PYTHONPATH gives no output at all. No idea why.

Comment: Would you try ```export PYTHONPATH=/hjs/jen/projects/my_env``` and see if that alters the output from ```python -c "import sys; print '\n'.join(sys.path)"```

Comment: Sorry I've forgotten to add an important detail. The aim of this work is to build a conda environment to replace bash exports. Therefore bash exports has been disabled.

Comment: Ah, I see. Apologies, I've never used conda before so I can't be more help!